# Round Robin Scheduling with CPU and IO Operations

Tags: operating-system, job-scheduling, round-robin

Two processes A and B with the same priority are executed in a round-robin method with a time slice of 30 milliseconds on a single CPU, but they use respectively different I/O devices. When they are executed as a standalone process, their processing times and sequences are shown in the figure below. How long (in milliseconds) does it take to complete both processes?  Here, the two processes are alternately executed; that is, the first is A, the second B, and then A again. The multi-processing overhead of OS can be ignored, and both CPU and I/O operations can be executed concurrently.

[Click here to see the image relevant to the given problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya7Sb.png)

The choices are 150, 160, 170, and 180
How do we arrive with 170?

This question is taken from the Fundamental IT Engineer Examination

Answer (score 0):

For a timeline:

```
T = 0 to 10 ms: Process A is using CPU (then blocks and process B starts)
T = 10 to 70 ms: Process B is using CPU.
```

At this point we have a race condition. Either Process B manages to start its IO in the last possible instant, or it doesn't.

If Process B manages to start its IO in the last possible instant, then:

```
T = 70 to 80 ms: Process A is using CPU, first 10 ms of Process B's IO happens too.
T = 80 to 130 ms: CPU is idle (both processes doing IO until Process B's IO completes and Process A's IO has 10 ms left).
T = 130 to 160 ms: Process B is using CPU (and last 10 ms of Process A's IO is occuring). I assume Process B finishes and terminates after this.
T = 160 to 170 ms: Process A is using CPU. I assume Process A finishes and terminates after this.
```

If Process B doesn't start its IO in the last possible instant, then:

```
T = 70 to 80 ms: Process A is using CPU (none of Process B's IO happens because it wasn't started).
T = 80 to 80 ms: Process B gets the last tiny moment needed to start its IO and blocks.
T = 80 to 140 ms: CPU is idle (both processes doing IO until both Processes' IO completes at the "same" time).
```

At this point there's a second race condition - either Process A's IO will complete a fraction of a nanosecond sooner or Process B's IO will complete a fraction of a nanosecond sooner.

If Process A's IO finished first then:

```
T = 140 to 150 ms: Process A is using CPU, then finishes
T = 150 to 180 ms: Process B is using CPU, then finishes
```

If Process B's IO finished first then:

```
T = 140 to 170 ms: Process B is using CPU, then finishes
T = 170 to 180 ms: Process A is using CPU, then finishes
```

Based on all of the above it's non-deterministic, and the total time will be either 170 ms or 180 ms (primarily depending on the 1st race condition).